# 'onSurfaceTextureUpdated' method doesn't call when POWER_KEY is pressed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textures, render-to-texture

I'm using TextureView to show some content in my app. The issue that I'm facing is that when I open new activity on top of it or take the application to background then onPause-> onStop methods are called as expected and on coming back the onStart-> onResume methods are called and 'onSurfaceTextureUpdated' method in TextureView is called. But when I press Power Key to lock/unlock the phone then though onPause-> onStop methods are calling but 'onSurfaceTextureUpdated' method is not calling inspite of same life cycle methods. And Black screen appears until I do some manual action to swipe or etc views. What could be possible reason for this?

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.fragment.MediaPreviewViewModel" />
    </data>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mediaLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <com.isaacudy.kfilter.KfilterView
                    android:id="@+id/ivThumbnailSurface"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/videoProgressBar"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.showProgressBar?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </layout>
```

Thanks